# Arquillian can not inject EJB

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have a testclass:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ActionServiceTest {

    @EJB
    private ActionService actionService;
...
}
```

This works fine. 
Now I created another File `ActionBuilder` which should also have the EJB injected (but has no @RunWith Annotation) and is called from the `ActionServiceTest`, e.g.

```
new ActionBuilder().foo()
```

.

```
public class ActionBuilder {

    @EJB
    ActionService actionService;
...
}
```

In this case `actionService` is `null`. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Are you using a microdeployment? Is the ActionService (and impl) included in the microdeployment?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `new` which will bypass any container injection.

Comment: how else should I create an instance of  ActionBuilder() ? Must it have an annotation @Stateless?

Comment: You could make it an ejb as well, or you could use cdi to inject it.